# How can I divide my country level data equally into 5 groups in rworldmap?

Tags: r, rworldmap

I have a set of country level data globally. The data format is something like this:

```
    Item | Country | Var1 
    1    |  US     |  14 
    2    |  UK     |  12 
    3    |  France |  11 
    . . . . 
    180  |  Russia |  0
```

My code using rworldmap for map plot is:

```
x <- joinCountryData2Map(df, joinCode="country.name", nameJoinColumn = "Country")
mapParams <- mapCountryData(x,nameColumnToPlot = "Var1", 
               xlim = NA, 
               ylim = NA, 
               mapRegion = "World",
               numCats = 5,
               catMethod = "quantiles",
               addLegend = FALSE, 
               mapTitle = "Rplot1",
               colourPalette = c("topo"))
do.call(addMapLegend, c(mapParams,legendLabels = "limits"
                        ,legendWidth=0.5
                        ,legendIntervals="data"
                        ))
```

I am able to do the map plot with quantiles, but I will also need to do plot with equal value intervals. How can I divide the values in Var1 into 5 groups with equal intervals, for example [0,2],[3,5],[6,8],[9,11],[12,14]?
  Should I still use catMethod argument?  I would appreciate if anyone could help with this question.

Comment: `Hmisc::cut2()` shld do this IIRC. I don't use `rworldmap` but I think I remember it being able to take manual cuts like that.

Comment: I set attributes: numCats=N, catMethod = "pretty", and the graph seems to be plotted by equal intervals.